# Create different object by type using switch-case?

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

Good day every one,

We use a lot of statements like if-else or switch-case for creating different object depending on different conditions like:

```
interface Job {
    public function do();
}

class Auto implement Job {
    ...
}

class Month implement Job {
    ...
}

...
// another script to run jobs
...
switch($type) {
    case 'auto':
        $instance = new Auto();
        break;
    case 'month':
        $instance = new Month();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('not support type!');
}

$instance->do();
```

The problem is if we use if-else / switch-case make code grows fast with more and more types.
We can use reflection or dynamical instance initiation however the IDE (like PHPStorm) will not able to find the class usage..
Is there any better way against using switch-case?

Comment: Using Factory design pattern maybe? BTW PHPStorm 2016.1 just came out, new features added, maybe code completion will work for you now.

Comment: Hello @MuhammedM.  Yes, we use a Factory object to create object by switch-case, just wandering if there's any better way in Factory itself.  And BTW, I'll take a look to latest PHPStorm, thank you :)

Comment: maybe instead of switch do this, have array('auto','month').., then have validateInstances($instance) - which ensures $instance is in_array() or throws Exception, after what call $instance_ob = new $instance(); You reduce switch to 3 lines, but implement extra verify function, and array to hold values.

Comment: Yes, we can use a dynamic object creation by new $classname(), however the IDE wouldn't be able to find usages, but I think to have an extra validateInstances() as you mentioned is great.

Comment: To be honest, I was never in a situation where I preferred IDE finding class usages over my design implementation, but again it's your code you know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two answers really.

You should be type hinting `$instance` as the interface `Job`. That is the whole purpose of an `Interface` in OOP. You can do that with the following:

```
switch ($type) {
    case 'auto':
        $instance = new Auto();
        break;
    // ...
}

/** @var \Job $instance */
$instance->do();
```

You can provide metadata to PHPStorm for type hinting factory methods if you want to go that route. The metadata file can be committed to source control just like your code https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata